# asp.net mvc model validation with value match

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I would like to check user input of a zip code field to reject any input that isn't one of 3 specified values:

53119
53029
53214

Is it possible to do this with the built in model validation, or will I have to write something custom?

Comment: Why cant you use dropdown instead, if its just 3 values? Also, take a look at [Remote validation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808%28VS.98%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would propose that you wrote something custom if there is any chance that this list will change in the future, but it is indeed possible doing something like this:

```
public class UserModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Zip")]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^(53119|53029|53214)", ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Valid Zip")]
    public string ZipCode{ get; set; } 
}
```